# React Native iOS Build Error: 'No Type or Protocol Named RCTBridgeModule' on M3 Mac

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, livekit

I've integrated a new module, LiveKit, into my React Native (v0.73.1) app. It works fine on Android, but building the iOS version results in an error: "No Type or Protocol named 'RCTBridgeModule'." I've tried:

- Updating Header Search Paths in Xcode.
- Running `pod install` in the `ios` directory.
- Using `.xcworkspace` file.
- Executing `arch -x86_64 react-native run-ios`.
- Ensuring no duplicate React Native links.

Error logs: [Pastebin Link](https://pastebin.com/Tn9j5UYB)

Looking for suggestions to resolve this iOS-specific issue.

Comment: can you please post complete error log you receive?

Comment: This was a bug in the library, fixed in 1.4.3